# Determine whether an event is invoked by .trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to determine whether or not the `.change` function below is being called by the jQuery `.trigger`?

```
    $('input[name=TransactionType]').change(function () {
        //Clear out values
        $('input:text').val('');
        $('input:text').text('');

        //Display input fields
        var radioValue = $(this);

        $('#RightDiv').children().each(function () {
            if (radioValue.attr('id') == $(this).attr('id')) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Add an alert or `console.log()` to the handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `event.isTrigger`

```
 $('input[name=TransactionType]').change(function (e) {
    if(e.isTrigger){
      //This was triggered using trigger('change') or .change() etc
    }
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JZuR2/)

This flag is set only when it is triggered as mentioned above otherwise you may get it undefined. I am not able to find any documentation though.

But i see this being set in the jquery code in the trigger method.

```
 // Trigger bitmask: & 1 for native handlers; & 2 for jQuery (always true)
 event.isTrigger = onlyHandlers ? 2 : 3;
```